# Add tags to AppSync logs CDK

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync API and I would like to add tags to this log group created:

```
const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, 'Api', {
  name: 'demo',
  schema: 'schema.graphql',
  authorizationConfig: {
    defaultAuthorization: {
      authorizationType: appsync.AuthorizationType.API_KEY,
    },
  },
  xrayEnabled: true,
  logConfig: {
    fieldLogLevel: appsync.FieldLogLevel.ALL
  }
});
```

But adding tags in the following manner only adds them to the API and not the log group:

```
const app = new cdk.App();
new ApiStack(app, 'ApiStack');

Tags.of(app).add('environment', 'dev');
```

Is there any way to make sure the log group is also tagged?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I had to explicitly create the log group in the following manner so that the tags are added as CDK dynamically creates the log group and the tags are not added in that manner.

```
const logGroup = new LogGroup(stack, 'AppSyncLogGroup', {
  logGroupName: `/aws/appsync/apis/${api.apiId}`,
});
```

The log group name should be the same format as above.

Comment: How did you then connect the logGroup with the Appsync-Api? In my case an error is thrown, that this log-group exists already. Then I do "LogGroup.fromLogGroupName" and add Tags this, but these tags are not added actually....

Comment: You don't need to do the `LogGroup.fromLogGroupName` anymore. This automatically adds the tags that you added to the app to this log group

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately running the above recommended code results in an error in my case. Resource of type 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup' with identifier '{"/properties/LogGroupName":"/aws/appsync/apis/XXXXXX"}' already exists.

Comment: Try re-deploying the stack? I can create a sample repo that you can have a look at

Comment: Correction: this did not work for me.  Tried to use an Aspect as well and that did not work either.